# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined when use http in service in Angular 6

Tags: angular, http, service

I have two services. One is core service and one specific service.
In core service I make http request. In Angular 6 it is does not work.
(In Angular 7 works perfect).

In Angular 6 I get **Cannot read property 'get' of undefined** on http.

Here is my code:

**query-service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class QueryService {
  protected apiUrl: string = 'http://localhost:4200';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public query(uri: string): Observable<any> {
    const url = this.apiUrl + '/' + uri;

    return this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'json', withCredentials: true});
  }
}
```

**client-search.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Client} from '../models/client';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {QueryService} from '../services/query.service';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ClientSearchService extends QueryService {

  public list(uri: string): Observable<any> {
    const clientResponse = this.query(uri);

    return clientResponse.pipe(
      map(data => data.collection),
      map((records: Client[]) => records.map((client: Client) => Client.factory(client)))
    );
  }

}
```

**client-search.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Client} from '../models/client';
import {ClientSearchService} from './client-search.service';
import {ClientsShareService} from '../services/clients-share.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-crm-client-search',
  templateUrl: './client-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client-search.component.css']
})

export class ClientSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  public client: Client = new Client();
  public clientList: Client[];

  constructor(public clientSearchService: ClientSearchService, public clientsShareService: ClientsShareService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    const clientsList = this.clientSearchService.list('assets/files/clients.json');

    clientsList.subscribe((clients: Client[]) => {
      this.clientList = clients;
      this.clientsShareService.setData(clients);
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: Have you imported the HttpClientModule into your app.module.ts?

Comment: @Shane if he doesn't import it, will get the StaticInjectorError not this error.

Comment: I have imported HttpClientModule. Problem is that the same application works on Angular 7 but do not work on Angular 6

Answer (score 1):

Your child class only has the default constructor, but the parent does not have one. So angular is creating an instance of `ClientSearchService` without injecting the `HttpClient` service.

As it is, you currently have this:

```
ClientSearchService extends QueryService {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
}
```

You need to add a non-default constructor to the child class as follows:

```
export class ClientSearchService extends QueryService{
 constructor(http: HttpClient){
   super(http)
 }
 ...
}
```

Comment: But Why constructor from parent is not exists in child like in PHP :) ?

Comment: Most likely the behavior was changed as this is a common pitfall

Comment: Cant tell, I havent used php. But in any OOP language, if you extend a class without default constructor, then the child class **has to** explicitly call the non-default parent constructor.

Comment: In Angular 7 it works without create constructor in child class

Comment: @DanielCzęstki Most likely the result of https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/24014